# Type of Derived Class from Base Pointer C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism, typedef

This is the scenario:

```
class Base {
public:
  typedef Base type;
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
  typedef Derived type;
};
```

I want something like:

```
int main() {
  Base * bs = new Derived();

  decltype(*bs)::type newvar;
}
```

How can i do something like above to get the type of the Derived class without using static / dynamic cast ?

Comment: why do both of these typedefs need be named the same? I feel like this could cause some confusion for the program farther down the road..

Comment: If I change the typename how can i get it to work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do that.

C++ is statically typed language, which means a type has to be determined at compile time.
In the example `bs` doesn't know what object type it's pointing.
See a scenario below to make it clearer:

```
Base * bs = (bool)? new Base() : new Derived();
```

You have to rely on `virtual` mechanism or `dynamic_cast` for achieving your ultimate purpose.

Comment: @Itzurabhi You *are* using TMP in your code. But that doesn’t change what iammilind said in his answer: you cannot mix static and dynamic typing in this way.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `*bs` has in fact two types: A static type, i.e. the type it is declared with, and that is `Base`. The other type is the dynamic type, which is the type of the object it actually points to, in your case `Derived`. The static type is the only type that is known at compile time, and it can't be changed. TMP, normal function calls and all the template stuff happens at compile time, so only the static type applies for those, too.

The *only* ways to use the dynamic type are to explicitly say that to the compiler, meaning to call a virtual function or using `dynamic_cast`.

You say you want "something like" the code you are showing - what do you want to accomplish with that? I am pretty sure the answer will be "use virtual functions if you want to do things depending of the dynamic type", since `dynamic_cast` normally is not a real option.

Comment: I need the type to pass into std::is_same

Comment: `is_same` is a template and thus has only access to the static type. What do you want to accomplish with `is_same`? Describe the goal, not the means you try to use to achieve that goal ;)

Comment: To get something like `is_same` for the dynamic type, you have to delay the evaluation until runtime and use virtual functions, normally for both objects. That problem is known as "double dispatch" which can be rather tedious in C++. Maybe you want to look it up to get some ideas how to accomplish the comparison.

Comment: just want to know if i can avoid static cast using templates :)

Comment: `static_cast` has nothing to do with your question, at all. Or with `is_same`